# Undefined index -

Tags: php, mysql, postman

Hola tengo una consulta sobre php que no me realiza la insercion de datos
estoy queriendo hacer un INSERT en mi tabla de mysql y me esta dando error, la conexion la realiza correctamente, pero no puedo salir de ese error.

Alguien sabe como poder solucionarlo?

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$equipo=$_POST['equipo'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$marca=$_POST['marca'];
$modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
$serial=$_POST['serial'];
$local=$_POST['local'];
$departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
$oficina=$_POST['oficina'];
$piso=$_POST['piso'];

// $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `equiposbdphp`");


$con->query('INSERT INTO `equiposbdphp` (`equipo`, `tipo`, `marca`, `modelo`, `serial`, `local`, `departamento`, `oficina`, `piso`) VALUES (\'' . $equipo . '\', \'' . $tipo. '\', \'' . $marca . '\', \'' . $modelo. '\', \'' . $serial. '\', \'' . $local . '\' ,\'' . $departamento . '\',\'' . $oficina . '\',\'' . $piso . '\')');

$query->bind_param('sssssssss',$equipo,$tipo,$marca,$modelo,$serial,$local,$departamento,$oficina,$piso);
$query->execute();

$resultado=$sentencia->get_result();
    if ($fila =$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    $query->close();
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

en el postman me sale el siguiente error

```
La conexion se realizó correctamente<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: equipo in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: tipo in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: marca in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: modelo in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: serial in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: local in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: departamento in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: oficina in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: piso in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: con in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in
D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\conexion\validacion.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
```

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: los  esta enviando desde un formulario con `method="POST"`  ya que por lo que se ve estas intentando solo ejecutar esa pagina! podrias validar los cambos antes o colocar esto al principio `if(!isset($_POST)){ die("no estas enviando datos por post!");}`

Comment: La validación anterior no es la mejor ya que si te envían solo 1 clave de todas las que tiene pasará tu validación y arrojará el mismo error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no estás pasando los respectivos parámetros, al menos no mediante el método POST.

Si los parámetros no llegan, `$_POST` será un arreglo vacío y no contendrá las claves. Esto produce el error que mencionas.

Si te aseguras de pasar todos los parámetros debería funcionar, pero no seria lo más optimo. Puedes comprobar si el arreglo de `$_POST` contiene una clave o no con `isset()`. Si la clave existe es porque viene el parámetro con algún valor.

```
$equipo= isset($_POST['equipo']) ? $_POST['equipo'] : 'DEFAULT_VALUE';
$tipo= isset($_POST['tipo']) ? $_POST['tipo'] : 'DEFAULT_VALUE';
... => todas tus otras variables
```

En el ejemplo anterior, si vienen las variables tomarán su valor, si no, uno por defecto. Esto lo conseguimos de manera sencilla con un operador ternario y aún puedes mantener parámetros opcionales, ya que de momento no estamos restringiendo nada.

> Si estás sobre php 7.X puedes reemplazar la sintaxis del operador ternario por un null coalesce.

Para asegurarte de que vienen las variables que requieres, debes validar el contenido.

```
if($equipo == 'DEFAULT_VALUE' && $tipo == 'DEFAULT_VALUE'         ...){
    // response for bad query
}


// YOUR CODE
```

OBS: Si estás enviando los datos por la URL del navegador estos siempre se enviarán por GET, no POST. Si estás usando un formulario asegúrate de tener especificado el método correcto. Si estás creando un webservice, puedes enviar los datos por alguna aplicación como postman.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo primero que todo te esta diciendo que la variable "con"(Tu variable de conexion a la base de datos no esta definida), revisa que tengas bien el nombre. Te dice que no puedes usar la funcion query() en una variable nula, en este caso es "con". Ahora con respecto al formulario te dice que lo que enviaste no esta definido por que estas intentando darle un valor a tus variables sin verificar si el formulario fue enviado. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como verificar si el formulario fue enviado con un input type="submit" name="submit".

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  include 'conexion.php';
  $equipo=$_POST['equipo'];
  $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
  $marca=$_POST['marca'];
  $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
  $serial=$_POST['serial'];
  $local=$_POST['local'];
  $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
  $oficina=$_POST['oficina'];
  $piso=$_POST['piso'];

  // $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `equiposbdphp`");


  $con->query('INSERT INTO `equiposbdphp` (`equipo`, `tipo`, `marca`, `modelo`, `serial`, `local`,       `departamento`, `oficina`, `piso`) VALUES (\'' . $equipo . '\', \'' . $tipo. '\', \'' . $marca . '\',   \'' . $modelo. '\', \'' . $serial. '\', \'' . $local . '\' ,\'' . $departamento . '\',\'' . $oficina   . '\',\'' . $piso . '\')');

  $query>bind_param('sssssssss',$equipo,$tipo,$marca,$modelo,$serial,$local,$departamento,$oficina,$pis);
  $query->execute();

  $resultado=$sentencia->get_result();
  if ($fila =$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
      echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  }
  $query->close();
  $conexion->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

debes validar los campos antes de asignarlos

pordrias hacer algo como esto:

```
$f=false;
$validar = array('equipo', 'tipo', 'marca', 'modelo', 'serial','local', 'departamento', 'oficina', 'piso');

for($i = 0; $i < count($validar) ; $i++){
 if(!isset($_POST[$validar[$i]])){
    echo "el campo {$validar[$i]} no esta definido!";
    $f=true;

  }
}

if($f){
  die("verifica los campos y vuelve a intentar;");
}
 // resto del codigo
 $equipo=$_POST['equipo'];
  $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
  $marca=$_POST['marca'];
  $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
  $serial=$_POST['serial'];
  $local=$_POST['local'];
  $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
  $oficina=$_POST['oficina'];
  $piso=$_POST['piso'];
```